# Is it possible to assign color to targeted coordinates x to y without having to upload a UIimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, coordinates

I want to know whether it is possible to assign colors to different coordinates in the IOS and how it can be accomplished. In other words for example making a black square by assigning colors to x,y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you question, I have understood that you are looking for API to fill a pixel with a color based on the coordinates. To achieve this you can use UIBezierPath class. I wrote a sample example to achieve this.

I have created a subclass of UIView called CustomView and overriden drawRect method like below :

```
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];

    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    [path fill];
}
```

UIBezierPath class can be used to lay your custom drawing on your view. A path basically represents an area where you can fill different colors in it. The above example will draw a rectangle at x = 50 y = 50 coordinates with width and height of 100 each.

If you want to just fill color to a point, then create bezier path instance like below :

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 1, 1)];
```

Replace your's View Controller's class name from UIView to CustomView. When you run your app you should see following output :

[image]

Comment: if i use this only changing colour static,while user touches the screen i have x and y coordinator using that i am trying to change colour ,is it possible

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague and doesn't really make sense. Yes, you could develop an app that stored a grid of pixel colors and then drew them to the screen. However a UIImage or a CGImage (the underlying data structure behind a UIImage) is a good native way to represent pixel data on iOS.

What you typically do is create an off-screen graphics context and draw into that context, then extract an image from the context.

Comment: Look's like you understood it and it made sense to the user above which therefore has answered my question. Thank you for the unnecessary comment.